# Check or uncheck various inputs based on selected selection option

Tags: jquery, forms

I'd like to change which checkboxes are checked based on which age is selected.

If `adult` is selected the first check box should be marked and the second unmarked. If `16-17` both should marked and if `Under 15` only the second checkbox should be marked.

I suspect I need to use something other then `on("click",` but I'm not sure what the proper code is. There will be several other boxes to check/uncheck based on the selection but if I can get the right hooks I'm sure I can figure the rest out.

```js
$('#age15').on("click", function() {
  var ybox1 = $(input[name = "idparent"]);
  ybox1.prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="age">
    <span class="<?=$braerr?>">Age </span>
    <select id="age" name="age" value=""  tabindex="">
        <option value="">Choose Age</option>
        <option id="age15" value="Under16" <?=($age=="Under16"?$sel:"");?>>Under 16</option>
        <option id="age1617" value="16-17" <?=($age=="16-17"?$sel:"");?>>16-17</option>
        <option id="ageadult" value="Adult" <?=($age=="Adult"?$sel:"");?>>Adult</option>
    </select>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="dlid" name="dlid" value="dlid" <?if($hasdlid=="dlid")echo "checked=\"checked\"";?>>
<label for="dlid">Valid Driver's License, Learner's Permit, or State/Military ID</label>


<input type="checkbox" id="idparent" name="idparent" value="idparent" <?if($hasidparent=="idparent")echo "checked=\"checked\"";?>>
<label for="idparent">Copy of Parent's ID (Front and Back)</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way to interact with a `select` element is to hook an event handler to its `change` event. Attaching `click` event handlers to the `option` elements isn't well supported in modern browsers.

Within the `change` event handler you can get the `value` which was selected, then set the `checked` property of either checkbox based on that value. Given the logic you described in the question, it would look something like this:

```js
let $dlid = $('#dlid');
let $idparent = $('#idparent');

$('#age').on("change", e => {
  let age = e.target.value;
  $dlid.prop('checked', age === 'Adult' || age === '16-17');
  $idparent.prop('checked', age === 'Under16' || age === '16-17');    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="age">
  <span class="<?=$braerr?>">Age </span>
  <select id="age" name="age" value=""  tabindex="">
    <option value="">Choose Age</option>
    <option id="age15" value="Under16">Under 16</option>
    <option id="age1617" value="16-17">>16-17</option>
    <option id="ageadult" value="Adult">Adult</option>
  </select>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="dlid" name="dlid" value="dlid" />
<label for="dlid">Valid Driver's License, Learner's Permit, or State/Military ID</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="idparent" name="idparent" value="idparent" />
<label for="idparent">Copy of Parent's ID (Front and Back)</label>
```